# Oracle Table field TYPE declaration issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I  have a procedure where I am using `%TYPE` to declare my variable. As of now its working for only one table i.e. `EMPLOYEES`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE
DECLARE
filed2 EMPLOYEES.name%TYPE;
END;
```

Now I want to extent it for others table which have same few common tables. So I will pass the table name as parameter. Here how can use the `TYPE` syntax because table name is in variable. If I am trying this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (myTable IN VARCHAR2)
DECLARE
filed2 myTable.name%TYPE;
END;
```

I am getting an error. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Type declaration is static. It can be inferred using `%type`, but that will still compile to a static type definition.

In your case, you try to reference a 'property' from a `varchar2`, which is not possible (Oracle doesn't have properties on `varchar2`).

Comment: @CrazyC: need more help?